# jQuery UI sortable for li items in Bootstrap 3 nav

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple Bootstrap 3 navbar having the following HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to make the `li` elements sortable: to be able do reorder them.

I tried:

```
$("ul>li").sortable();
```

I can drag the pages, but I can't drop them in another place (like in the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default)).

How can I fix this behaviour?

See the follwing: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tFmnE/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only class name `.name` instead element name as a selector

```
$(".nav").sortable();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tFmnE/1/)

Comment: It's ok, it happens! Glad it helped